# Can't download file now that filetransfer is deprecated

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, file-transfer

I wrote a Ionic 4 application. I wanted to update it and it seems that filetransfer is now deprecated, so I removed it. the problem is, now I can't download files. Documentation says it can be replaced by XMLHttpRequest, like in the link below, which I followed to make a new "downloadFiles" function.
https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html

But this solution makes me struggle with CORS issue. I can't set the correct CORS header (allow origin and stuff) on the server because I can't edit it.

What is the right way to download files now with Ionic ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: Use this plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer

Comment: As I said in the topic, I can't because it is deprecated :,(

Comment: Its not deprecated. It is working fine in my applications. I think you are missing something.

Comment: This plugin was deprecated until a recent vote by the Apache Cordova PMC decided to undeprecate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution with the plugin cordova-plugin-advanced-http

first install plugin

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
npm install @ionic-native/http
```

then use it to get blob, it bypass cors issues

```
 import { HTTP, HTTPResponse } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

 constructor(
   private adHTTP: HTTP
 )
 ...
  const reqOptions: any = {
    method: 'get',
    responseType: 'blob'
  };
  let res: HTTPResponse = await this.adHTTP.sendRequest(source, reqOptions);
  let blob: Blob = res.data;
  await this.file.writeFile(path, filename, blob, { replace: true });
```